# How to prevent shared viewmodel for usercontrols?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Let me try and explain my problem.

I am using an MVVM pattern in an ASP.NET Web Forms application.

Each usercontrol has a backing ViewModel and I am initializing them using:

```
public TViewModelInterface ViewModel {
    get {
        return IoC.Resolve<TViewModelInterface>();
    }
}
```

This code is present inside a ViewBase class declared like so:

```
public abstract class ViewBase<TUserControl, TViewInterface, TViewModelInterface> : UserControl, IView
    where TUserControl : UserControl
    where TViewInterface : class, IView
    where TViewModelInterface : class, IViewModel {
```

Now, it's all nice and fine as long as the UserControl is not used at multiple places in the same ASPX page.

When that is done, bam! Both the UserControl instances share the same TViewModelInterface instance!

Till now I was using Per Request init strategy for the View Model interfaces. I am thinking of making it Transient and caching the instance inside the ViewBase (so essentially inside a UserControl instance.)

Is that the best approach? I hope I made my question clear.

PS: IoC.Resolve is just a wrapper over Unity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is only a question of configuring your dependency container appropriately. You seem to resolve in sort of singleton mode which yields same instance for each `Resolve<TViewModelInterface>` query. There are choices to resolve in multiton or a plethora of other modi - yielding a new instance per query, for example.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: Actually, I am already using the 'transient' mode to give multiple instances. I am caching it the first time it is used in a UserControl. That allows me avoid this problem.